# JAVA: json string to Map<string, string> (or an object)

Tags: java, json

I'm looking for a simple json library to convert json-string to Map or a POJO object. I know it's a duplicate, still I got specific requirements:

1. **no weird dependencies** like [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) (why do you need all of them for a simple task?)
2. use few lines of codes to accomplish it (KISS principle).
3. I prefer conversion to Map but POJO will be good almost as well.

that's it.
what do you suggest?

Comment: Any reason to avoid dependencies? May be you can look at source of those libraries and re-write it on your own. Because essentially those libraries also doing same.

Comment: I don't understand the use of all those extra jars as dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jackson](http://www.jackson.codehaus.org) would be best in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Jackson is good, but I think you can also give [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) a try.
It's simple and easy to use. And there is a unit test for converting json string to Map and vice versa. 
Check this:[MapTest.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/search?q=MapTest&origq=MapTest&btnG=Search%20Trunk)

Hope this help you.